# Add "..." when hide text and remove them when show text

Tags: jquery

Need to add '...' to the end text. Then after click on button show big text and need hide this '...' (as used in seo text in e-commerce).

```
            <div class="us-html-box-text hideblock">{{ html }}</div>
            <div class="slide-read-more-button">{{ more }}</div>

            <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
               var box = $(".us-html-box-text.hideblock");
               var minimumHeight = 100; // max height in pixels
               var initialHeight = box.innerHeight();
               if (initialHeight > minimumHeight) {
                  box.css('height', minimumHeight);
                  $(".slide-read-more-button").show();
               }
              
               SliderReadMore();

               function SliderReadMore() {
                  $(".slide-read-more-button").on('click', function () {
                    var currentHeight = box.innerHeight();
                    var autoHeight = box.css('height', 'auto').innerHeight();
                    var newHeight = (currentHeight | 0) === (autoHeight | 0) ? minimumHeight : autoHeight;

                     box.css('height', currentHeight).animate({
                        height: (newHeight)
                     })
                     $('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: box.offset().top
                     });
                  });
               }
            });
            </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try add these CSS to the text that you want to hide:

```
/* hide overflow text and show ellipsis */
.truncate {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

/* only ellipsis if the text exceeds the specified number of lines */
.line-clamp {
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 3; /* ellipsis when more than 3 lines */
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Then use an element to toggle the text show & hide status:

```
$("#show-more-1").click(function() {
  $("#first").toggleClass("truncate");
});

$("#show-more-2").click(function() {
  $("#second").toggleClass("line-clamp");
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
$("#show-more-1").click(function() {
  $("#first").toggleClass("truncate");
});

$("#show-more-2").click(function() {
  $("#second").toggleClass("line-clamp");
});
```

```css
.line-clamp {
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.truncate {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 200px;">
  <h4>Truncate</h4>
  <p id="first" class="truncate">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </p>
  <button id="show-more-1" type="button">Toggle</button>
  <hr />
  <h4>Line Clamp</h4>
  <p id="second" class="line-clamp">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </p>
  <button id="show-more-2" type="button">Toggle</button>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```